# Addhelpbutton in moodle

Tags: authentication, registration, moodle

I am using Moodle 2.3 
I am trying to add help button to my self registration form in moodle. I am making changed in
*`/login/signup_form.php`* page.

I am using:

```
 $mform->addHelpButton('country','country','moodle');
```

This creates a help icon on the page. But clicking on the icon it loads the help information on the same page. The pop up doesn't work. No JavaScript errors found in firebug.

Plz help

Comment: What's written in your language file? the strings $string['country'] and $string['country_help']

Comment: Yes i have  $string['country'] and $string['country_help']

Answer (score 0):

You need to on ajax/javascript setting from the admin.

```
Site administration > Appearance > AJAX and Javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also add an entry to lang/en/moodle.php

For example
In course/edit_form.php I added the following field

// Course Champion
$mform->addElement('text', 'champion', 'Champion', get_string('champion'), 'size="256"');
// New field
$mform->addHelpButton('champion','courseChampion');
// Field help
$mform->setDefault('champion', 'Firstname Lastname');

Then in lang/en/moodle.php I added the help information for that field.
$string['courseChampion'] = 'Course Champion';
$string['courseChampion_help'] = 'Enter the firstname and lastname of the champion.';

Answer (score 0):

In moodle.php under /root/lang/en, add the following string:

$string['country_help'] = 'Your text here';

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, is to add a help button not a translation...